# Use a matrix for layout in R. Why are points not drawn at their coordinates?

Tags: r, plot, layout, coordinates, igraph

everybody!

I'm trying to use ***igraph*** in R and plot the vertices and edges of a random graph. The coordinates of each vertex are randomly sampled from (0,1) and stored in a row of a matrix, ***CENTERS***. However, after ***using layout=CENTERS***, some of the points are apparently drawn elsewhere (negative x-/y- coordinate).

```
n = 5
r = 0.1
# randomly assign coordinates to n points
CENTERS <- matrix(0, nrow = n, ncol = 2)
for (t in 1:n)
{
  CENTERS[t,1] <- runif(1)
  CENTERS[t,2] <- runif(1)
}
# create adjacency matrix
# decide connect or not by distance
M <- matrix(0, nrow = n, ncol = n)
for (i in 1:n)
{
  for (j in 1:n)
  {
    if (i != j)
    {
      dist <- sqrt(sum((CENTERS[i,]-CENTERS[j,])^2))
      if (dist < 2*r) {M[i,j] <- 1}
    }
  }
}
# plot the random graph
g <- graph.adjacency(M)
plot(g, layout=CENTERS, axes = TRUE, 
     edge.arrow.mode=0, edge.color="black", edge.width=2,
     vertex.label=NA, vertex.color="red", vertex.shape='square', vertex.size=5)
```

[Plot of the randam graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0tJVt.png)

Why does it happen? How can I make sure that each vertex is placed at its coordinates? Thank you!

Comment: It looks to me that the `CENTERS` are scaled to fit the [-1,1] range.

Answer (score 0):

As @nicola suggested,  igraph plotting rescales the data to the range -1 to 1 for both x and y. You can suppress that behavior if you want by specifying `rescale=FALSE`.  However, even with `rescale=FALSE`, `plot.igraph` sets the plotting limits to -1 to 1. So you also need to set `xlim` and `ylim`.   I think that what you are looking for is:

```
plot(g, layout=CENTERS, axes = TRUE, 
     edge.arrow.mode=0, edge.color="black", edge.width=2,
     vertex.label=NA, vertex.color="red", vertex.shape='square', vertex.size=5,
     rescale=FALSE, xlim=c(0,1), ylim=c(0,1))
```

[image: graph - not rescaled]